# Linux ss to inspect netlink socket, what does 'Local Address' and 'Port' mean?

Tags: linux, socket, netlink

What do `Local Address` and `Port` mean in `ss -f netlink` output?

I was expecting the `-n` numeric version `Local Address` to be `pid` but they do not seem to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `Local Address` part identifies the subsystem the netlink socket is used for (like `rtnl`, `selinux`, `audit`, `nft`, `uevent` and others), or some numerical encoding of that if you use the `-n` option.

The `Port` part is the PID (or `<process name>/<PID>` if you don't use the `-n` option). If the `Port` part is 0, it apparently means "kernel".

Some (mostly `uevent`, or `Local Address` code 15) netlink sockets seem to have large negative or positive numbers as their `Port` values: I have no clue about those.

Comment: thanks. I think you are right on the port part. For the Local Address, I verified in the iproute2 source, it is the 'protocol' when opening the socket. In lib/rtnames.c, char* nl_proto_tab[] has the mapping from protocol to displayed name, such as NETLINK_ROUTE <-> "rtnl", NETLINK_SOCK_DIAG <-> "tcpdiag"

Comment: btw, the display logic lives in misc/ss.c/netlink_show_one(), with address resolution code in nl_proto_n2a()

Comment: Reading the `man 7 netlink` section *Address formats*, I think the very large pos/neg numbers for `uevent` `Port` values are just kernel generated fake unique pids for a socket. Sadly `ss` does not print process name for netlink sockets, even with the `-p` parameter.